# How to manually construct a gzip so that compressed file is larger than original?

Tags: gzip, huffman-code, compression

Suppose a 1KB file called `data.bin`, If it's possible to construct a gzip of it `data.bin.gz`, but much larger, how to do it?

How much larger could we theoretically get in GZIP format?

Comment: see https://www.quora.com/Could-a-compressed-file-be-bigger-than-its-original

Comment: alright, I wanna hear why this isn't programming and **** people want to close this question.

Comment: I have no idea. Looks like a programming question for me :-)

Comment: I think the main idea here is that if the information is "zippable" (there are repeating patterns that can be replaced by something that takes less space to store), then you can zip, otherwise, the zip file will only add overhead adding metadata to something that can't be compressed. For example: someone tries to zip a zipped file.

Comment: Just because it was so easy to google, I don't think it would be honest to add an answer here just to earn points. But I haven't downvoted because it looked like an honest question (not a homework one). In fact, probably someone will close this saying it's dup

Comment: I guess, that very small files can be larger, because GZIP may use some space for headers. Also archive can store filename, so, archived file with very long name can be larger that the body of the file itself. And so on...

Comment: @est Close! Close everything! More closures for the god of closures! WAAAGH!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make it arbitrarily large. Take any gzip file and insert as many repetitions as you like of the five bytes: `00 00 00 ff ff` after the gzip header and before the deflate data.

Comment: haha, good exploit of the GZIP format. However can we do anything directly with the huffman table and compression algorithm?

Comment: Specifically, it is an "exploit" of the deflate compressed data format.

Comment: You could have no matches and arrange for the Huffman codes of all of the used byte values to have a length of 15 bits (assuming that only some of the byte values are used). Then, including headers, the result would be a little over double the size of the uncompressed data. I don't think you could make it much bigger without inserting empty or nearly empty deflate blocks, as in my answer. You could, for example, encode only one byte per deflate block, with a hundred or more bytes of overhead for each block. However that's not much different than just inserting empty blocks.

Answer (score 2):

Summary:

- With header fields/general structure: effect is unlimited unless it runs into software limitations
- Empty blocks: unlimited effect by format specification
- Uncompressed blocks: effect is limited to 6x
- Compressed blocks: with apparent means, the maximum effect is estimated at 1.125x and is very hard to achieve

---

Take the gzip format ([RFC1952](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1952) (metadata), [RFC1951](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1951) (deflate format), [additional notes for GNU gzip](http://www.gzip.org/format.txt)) and play with it as much as you like.

## Header

There are a whole bunch of places to exploit:

- use optional fields (original file name, file comment, extra fields)
- bluntly append garbage (GNU gzip will issue a warning when decompressing)
- concatenate multiple gzip archives (the format allows that, the resulting uncompressed data is, likewise, the concatenation or all chunks).

  - An interesting side effect (a bug in GNU gzip, apparently): `gzip -l` takes the reported uncompressed size from the last chunk only (even if it's garbage) rather than adding up values from all. So you can make it *look* like the archive is (absurdly) larger/smaller than raw data.

These are the ones that are immediately apparent, you may be able to find yet other ways.

## Data

The general layout of "deflate" format is (RFC1951):

> A compressed data set consists of a series of blocks, corresponding to
> successive blocks of input data.  The block sizes are arbitrary,
> except that non-compressible blocks are limited to 65,535 bytes.
> <...>
> Each block consists of two parts: a pair of Huffman code trees that
> describe the representation of the compressed data part, and a
> compressed data part.  (The Huffman trees themselves are compressed
> using Huffman encoding.)  The compressed data consists of a series of
> elements of two types: literal bytes (of strings that have not been
> detected as duplicated within the previous 32K input bytes), and
> pointers to duplicated strings, where a pointer is represented as a
> pair <length, backward distance>.  The representation used in the
> "deflate" format limits distances to 32K bytes and lengths to 258
> bytes, but does not limit the size of a block, except for
> uncompressible blocks, which are limited as noted above.

### Full blocks

The `00 00 00 ff ff` that [Mark Adler suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37538550/648265) is essentially an empty, non-final block (RFC1951 section 3.2.3. for the 1st byte, 3.2.4. for the uncompressed block itself).
<sub>Btw, according to [gzip overview at the official site](https://www.gnu.org/software/gzip/) and the source code, Mark is the author of the decompression part...</sub>

### Uncompressed blocks

Using non-empty uncompressed blocks (see prev. section for references), you can at most create one for each symbol. The effect is thus limited to 6x.

### Compressed blocks

In a nutshell: some inflation is achievable but it's very hard and the achievable effect is limited. Don't waste your time on them unless you have a very good reason.

Inside compressed blocks (section 3.2.5.), each chunk is `[<encoded character(8-9 bits>|<encoded chunk length (7-11 bits)><distance back to data(5-18 bits)>]`, with lengths starting at 3. A 7-9-bit code unambiguously resolves to a literal character or a specific range of lengths. Longer codes correspond to larger lengths/distances. No space/meaningless stuff is allowed between chunks.
So the maximum for raw byte chunks is 9/8 (1.125x) - if *all* the raw bytes are with codes 144 - 255.
Playing with reference chunks isn't going to do any good for you: even a reference to a 3-byte sequence gives 25/24 (1.04x) at most.

That's it for static Huffman tables. Looking through the docs on dynamic ones, it optimizes the aforementioned encoding for the specific data or something. So, it should allow to make the ratio for the given data closer to the achievable maximum, but that's it.